# Dynamic array Element counter for loop trouble

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Hello I am trying to store some data into a dynamic array using a for loop and counter to put a bunch of data into an element like so :

```
int arry;

cout << "how many Revenue tiers do you want?: "; cin >> arry;
Revenue*  rev = new Revenue[arry];//dynamic array
for (int i = 0, Track_Num_Divisions = 1;Track_Num_Divisions, i  < arry; i++,Track_Num_Divisions++ )
{
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Revenue #"<<Track_Num_Divisions << endl;
    cout << "===========" << endl;
    cout << "<< Ok what is your division name?: " << endl; cin >> D;
    string set_Division_name(D);
    cout << "<< What is your division number?: " << endl;  cin >> DN;
    string set_Division_number(DN);
    while (DN.size() != 4)
    {
        cout << "<< Sorry! Your Division Number cannot exceed or be short of 4. " << endl; cin >> DN;
    }
    cout << "<< What is your number of employees?: " << endl; cin >> N;

    //This is where the error is:
    Revenue*  rev = new Revenue[i].Set_Number_employee(N);

    cout << "<< What is the Total sales?: " << endl; cin >> TS;
    double Set_Total_sales(TS);
    cout << "<< What is the total cost?: " << endl; cin >> TC;
    double Set_Total_cost(TC);
    cout << "<< What is the total Profit?: " << endl; cin >> P;
    double Set_Profit(P);

    //and here :
     cout << "<< The total cost per employee is: " << Revenue* rev = new Revenue[i].Get_CPE() << endl;
}
```

how do I solve these. Both of these say I need a class type.

Comment: The tried and true answer:  Use `std::vector`.  Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with that last line?

Comment: Also this: `double Set_Total_sales(TS);`  Explain what you're trying to accomplish here.  This doesn't do anything except declare a function, it doesn't call anything.

Comment: May I suggest you start from the beginning, and write smaller programs so that you understand each concept before you create a larger program.  There are a lot of things that are wrong in the code you posted, and maybe breaking this down into pieces and asking questions concerning each aspect would be better.

Comment: this is only a piece of the code I have a class on the top I just need the proper syntax to store data in the different elements in this array. It is also required that i use the dynamic array in this way. Do you need to look at all my code in order to know the answer?  If anything my class name is "Revenue"

Comment: Before answering the question, you need to provide more detail as to what those (fake) calls are supposed to be doing, such as `Set_Profit`, `Set_Total_Sales` etc.  If these calls are part of storing the names, then this code snippet is totally wrong -- it isn't just a simple "syntax change".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help (assuming that class Revenue has the given methods):

```
int arry;

cout << "how many Revenue tiers do you want?: "; cin >> arry;
Revenue* revs = new Revenue[arry];//dynamic array
for (int i = 0, Track_Num_Divisions = 1; i < arry; i++, Track_Num_Divisions++)
{
    Revenue& rev = *revs[i];
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Revenue #"<<Track_Num_Divisions << endl;
    cout << "===========" << endl;
    cout << "<< Ok what is your division name?: " << endl; cin >> D;
    rev.set_Division_name(D);
    cout << "<< What is your division number?: " << endl;  cin >> DN;
    while (DN != 4)
    {
        cout << "<< Sorry! Your Division Number cannot exceed or be short of 4. " << endl; cin >> DN;
    }
    rev.set_Division_number(DN);
    cout << "<< What is your number of employees?: " << endl; cin >> N;
    rev.Set_Number_employee(N);

    cout << "<< What is the Total sales?: " << endl; cin >> TS;
    rev.Set_Total_sales(TS);
    cout << "<< What is the total cost?: " << endl; cin >> TC;
    rev.Set_Total_cost(TC);
    cout << "<< What is the total Profit?: " << endl; cin >> P;
    rev.Set_Profit(P);

    //and here :
     cout << "<< The total cost per employee is: " << rev.Get_CPE() << endl;
}
delete [] revs; // free memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was trying to unnecessarily create objects while making the dynamic array. all I had to add was this  `rev[i].Set_Profit(P);` and erase this `Revenue& rev = *revs[i];`